Viridis color scale for ggcorrplot
I am making a correlation matrix using the package ggcorrplot. Within the package you can set a vector of three colors for the color scale bar using the colors = c(...) function however, I was wondering if there is a way to set the scale bar to any of the Viridis color palettes?
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

corr <- round(cor(mtcars),1)

ggcorrplot(corr)


ggcorrplot(corr,
           colors = c('purple','seagreen3','yellow'))


Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0

Have you tried adding scale_fill_gradientn(colours = viridis(256, option = "D")) to your plot? (Copy/pasted from the example at the bottom of your link)

Yes that worked, not sure how I overlooked that.

The question was answered based on @Gregor Thomas comment
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

corr <- round(cor(mtcars),1)

ggcorrplot(corr) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = viridis(256, option = 'D'))
#> Scale for fill is already present.
#> Adding another scale for fill, which will replace the existing scale.


ggcorrplot(corr) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = viridis(256, option = 'H'))
#> Scale for fill is already present.
#> Adding another scale for fill, which will replace the existing scale.


Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0

You can make a correlogram fairly easily without any additional packages too!
library(tidyverse)


data(mtcars)


correlated_data = mtcars |> 
  cor() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  rownames_to_column('measure1') |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -measure1,
               names_to = 'measure2',
               values_to = 'correlation') |> 
  mutate(correlation = round(correlation, 3)) |> 
  mutate(across(c(measure1:measure2), \(x) fct_inorder(x)))

ggplot(correlated_data, aes(x = measure1, y = measure2, fill = correlation)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'white') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'plasma')+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())


Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0
